# .fadeTo not working, position absolute

Tags: javascript, fadeto

I have a button, position absolute / z-index 1, that covers the page 100%.

There is an image that is also position absolute that covers the page 100%, z-index 0.

The simple task is to be able to click anywhere on the page and have the button fade out (I've tried fadeOut as well) and reveal the image.

I'm pretty new to jQ and js, however I've looked for an answer and can't find anything that matches this behavior.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="sf.css">

<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<body>  
    <button type="button" class="bttn">HAPPY!</button>
    <div class="img">
        <img src="damonSF.jpg">
    </div>
</body>
<script type="text/jscript" src="sf.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.js"></script>

</html>


img{
position:absolute;
width:100%;
height:100%;
top:0;
right:0;
bottom:0;
left:0;
z-index:0;
}

button{
position:absolute;
opacity:1.0;
width:100%;
height:100%;
text-align:center;
top:0;
right:0;
bottom:0;
left:0;
z-index:1;
}



$(document).ready(function(){

$('.bttn').click(function(){

    $('.bttn').fadeTo('fast', 0.0);
            });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.bttn').click(function () {
  $('.bttn').fadeTo( "slow" ,0.1);
});
```

check out http://jsfiddle.net/uGEVr/1/

Comment: thank you for the answer and the link, however this still showed no improvement when tested in Chrome and Safari.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery before/above javascript file.

it appears the simple answer was to make sure that the link to the jQuery file came before/above the link to the .js file.

once switched these two around fadeTo worked great.